# How to check if the line chart has rendered in Cyress?

Tags: cypress, rendering

I am trying to fix this problem, but I couldn't.

I have a table containg many data on my website, and there is a line chart which presents the value of the row. If I click one row of the table, the line chart will change.

How do I check the line chart which has already changed if I click the table in Cypress?

Thanks!

---

Comment: How is your line chart rendered?

Comment: The line chart is related to the value of the table. If I click the table, then the line chart will be rendered and change .

Comment: It would be helpful to know what is the HTML for the line chart on the web page.

Comment: <app-linechart _ngcontent-oij-c129="" style="height: 570px; width: calc(100% - 248px);" _nghost-oij-c125="">  <div _ngcontent-oij-c125="" style="height: inherit; width: 100%;"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand"><div class=""></div></div>   <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink"><div class=""></div></div></div>   <canvas _ngcontent-oij-c125="" width="575" height="570" style="display: block; width: 575px; height: 570px;" class="chartjs-render-monitor">[object Object]</canvas></div></app-linechart>